# In VB, calculating the 5th working day of every month

Tags: vb.net, date

In VB, what coding could I use to calculate the 5th working day of every month? And if the 5th day is a holiday to go up one day.

Comment: Well, primarily you need to know what exactly are working days and what dates are holidays. Both aren't provided by VB or Windows.

Comment: Monday - Friday are working days. Holidays are New Years, Memorial Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving Day, Christmas Day, Independence Day. Those are the holidays I have stored in a table

Comment: It sounds simple, but the Federal guidelines are more complicated. For example, I believe it is the case that if Memorial Day falls on a Tuesday, the preceding Monday is the holiday. If the values are stored in a table, then you might be able to simply query for the values you want.

Comment: remember that working days and holidays differ greatly across the world. For example, I don't have a clue what all those holidays you listed are and not every country/region or profession in the world uses Monday to Friday as work week. My comment was rather about letting you know that (a) you need to have some preliminary work to do to properly support it and (b) there is nothing built-in to deal with that for you so unless you give more detail (or actually solve the problem yourself) no one will likely be able to help you.

Comment: The holidays aren't so difficult. In fact, I can only think of Labor Day being a possible candidate holiday to worry about. New Years, Independence day are too early in the month (1st and 4th, respectively), Memorial Day, Thanksgiving, and Christmas are too late in the month (last Monday of May, fourth Thursday of November, 25th of December), and Easter falls on a Sunday. None of these are candidates to be the 4th workday of a given month. Labor Day is the first Monday of September, so it can conceivably be the 5th workday of a month if the September starts on a Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a list of holiday dates with which to compare. You would need to build and store that list separately. You did not say what variant of VB (VBA? VB.NET?) but in VB.NET you could do:

```
Dim datevalue As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month, 1)
Dim dayIsFound As Boolean = False
Dim workDays As Integer

workDays = 1
While Not dayIsFound
    If ( dateValue.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday _ 
        And dateValue.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday _ 
        And Not HolidayList.Contains( dateValue )  _ 

        workDays = workDays + 1
    End If

    If  index >= 5 Then
        dayIsFound = True
    Else
        dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(1)
    End If
End While
```

Technically, it is possible to build an algorithm that determines the major holidays based on Federal guidelines (in the US) but it is complicated and may not conform to the holidays of the company to whom you are building this component.

Comment: Currently this would return dateValue = first WorkDay after the 5th day of the month.

I'll add an answer to get the code to format correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has 2 main components - first you need a list of public holidays, and second you need to count days of the week which are working days in your locale.

You can hard code your holidays for a quick solution, and if you want this code to keep working without modification you will need to Google for some algorithms / functions to calculate your holidays. Here is a link to some sample calculation functions for holidays, including Easter. http://www.cpearson.com/EXCEL/holidays.htm

Your main function can use the VB functions Weekday and WeekdayName (if needed) in conjunction with your list of public holidays to count all days that fall on a normal working day which isn't in your list of public holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Use Weekday function for Saturday and Sunday. Holidays are dependent on the location and country and you need to implement your own function for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count each valid working day until you get to the fifth one. E.g.

```
index = 0
Do
  If dateValue.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday _ 
      AndAlso dateValue.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday _ 
      AndAlso Not HolidayList.Contains( dateValue ) Then

     index = index + 1
     If index >= 5 Then _
        Exit Do
  End If
  dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(1)
Loop
```